# My JavaScript is not changing color or dimensions as I expected

Tags: javascript, android

I am trying to use JavaScript in an Android webview. I used following code. I did not get color changed or offset height of body.

```
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.addJavascriptInterface(new myJavaScriptInterface(webview), "jsInterface");

        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/sample/contents.html");
        //webview.loadData("file:///android_asset/sample",convertStreamToString(inputStream), "text/html", "UTF-8");

    webview.loadUrl("javascript:" +  
                "document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].style.color='red';" +  
                 "");

        wbview.loadUrl("javascript:window.jsInterface.EchoText(document.body.offsetHeight);");

        //webview.
}
class myJavaScriptInterface 
{
    WebView mywebview;
    public myJavaScriptInterface(WebView webview) 
    {
        this.mywebview=webview;
    }
    public void EchoText(String message) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(mywebview.getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because your page is not loaded (still loading) when you are using `webview.loadUrl("javascript:" + ...)` statements.

Try the following...

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/sample/contents.html");
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView webview, String url) {
        webview.loadUrl("javascript:" +  
            "document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].style.color='red';");
        wbview.loadUrl("javascript:" + 
            "window.jsInterface.EchoText(document.body.offsetHeight);");
    }
});
```